# How can I put image border to the image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In this, whenever I click on other object like tank or fighter at that time that golden border appear to that object and get hide from the first object.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Add your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nisarg you can use a list of boolean with all values false except the selected one and accordingly show the border. And suppose the user taps on the 3rd image then at index 2 you need to make the the boolean value as true and others as false

Comment: Hello Afridi Kayal how can I post the code to show you can you guide me?

Comment: Hello Deepak can you show because I flutter is new technology for me and I am beginner so I don't know how can I implement your opinion to my code

Comment: Hello Rohan My problem is that I can't make that same type of tab bar which I have mention above in the image that whenever I click on the one tab that golden border came around the tab icon and when I select another tab at that time from previous tab that border get hide and visible to the selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to add another image on the background image (ex. your badges). You can use `Stack` to solve your problem:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Image1 (background),
    Image2 (border)
  ],
)
```

note that you should follow the priority! because stack renders its children above each other.

Comment: How can I put the stack in TabBar

Comment: in TabBar you should provide a widget! and stack generates a widget too. So, you can provide `Stack` as a input for `TabBar`. for more information, share your code, so I can help throughly.

Comment: ya how can I share the code I am new here so I don't know many things in Stackoverflow, can you guide me how can I do that

Comment: you can share it by GitHub repo (and sharing the link) or add your code directly here in another comment or answer.

Comment: I have posted my code here if you requires the images which I have used then tell me then I will share that also

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Categories2 extends StatefulWidget {
  Categories2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Categories2State createState() => Categories2State();
}

class Categories2State extends State<Categories2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
          right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12),
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
        labelColor: Colors.red,
        indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
        indicatorWeight: 2,
        onTap: (index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              break;
            case 1:
              // ignore: unnecessary_statements
              Colors.red;
              break;
            case 2:
              // ignore: unnecessary_statements
              Icons.label;
              break;
            default:
          }
        },
        tabs: [
          new Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/tank.png',
                width: 28,
                height: 28,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Tank',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/fighter.png',
                width: 28,
                height: 28,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Fighter',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/assassin.png',
                width: 28,
                height: 28,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Assassin',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/mage.png',
                width: 28,
                height: 28,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Mage',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/marksman.png',
                width: 28,
                height: 28,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Marksman',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/support.png',
                width: 28,
                height: 28,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Support',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace each of this items:

```
Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/fighter.png',
                width: 28,
                height: 28,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Fighter',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

with:

```
Container(
            child: new Tab(
              icon: Stack(
                  children:[
                     Image.asset(
                         YOUR ICON PATH,
                         width: 28,
                         height: 28,
                      ),
                      Image.asset(
                         Your Border path,
                         width: 28,
                         height: 28,
                      ),
                  ]
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Fighter',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: but I want it like that when I click on fighter at that time that border will appear over fighter after that when I click on tank than at that time border will appear over tank and get removed from the fighter I want it like that so can you tell how can we do that thing